# Does jQuery have a handleout for .delegate('hover')?

Tags: jquery, delegates, handler

I am trying to use:

```
$('mydiv').delegate('hover', function() {  
    $('seconddiv').show();  
}, function() {  
    //For some reason jQuery won't run this line of code  
    $('seconddiv').hide();  
});
```

Comment: If you provide an example of your HTML, I can give an answer more specific to your markup.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

User113716's great answer will no longer work in **jQuery 1.9+**, because the *pseudo-event* `hover` is no longer supported ([upgrade guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#hover-pseudo-event)).

Also since **jQuery 3.0** `delegate()` for binding events is officially deprecated, so please use the *new* [`on()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for all event binding purposes.

You can easily migrate **user113716**'s solution by replacing `hover` with `mouseenter mouseleave` and switching to the `on()` syntax:

```
$('mydiv').on('mouseenter mouseleave', 'seconddiv', function(event) {
    $(this).toggle( event.type === 'mouseenter' );  
});
```

If your problem is more complex than a simple `toggle`, I suggest binding two separate events:

```
$('mydiv').on('mouseenter', 'seconddiv', function( event ) {
    // do something
}).on('mouseleave', 'seconddiv', function( event ) {
    // do something different
});
```

**NB:** Since `hover` was removed in v1.9 and `on()` was introduced in v1.7, there is no real need for a solution using `delegate()` - but if you like it for some reason; it is still there (for now) and does the job:

```
$('mydiv').delegate('seconddiv','mouseenter mouseleave', function(event) {
    $(this).toggle( event.type === 'mouseenter' );  
});
```

Comment: I had no idea you could bind two events using `on`

Comment: `delegate()` is deprecated in 3.0 https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-on-quot-ready-quot-fn-removed

Answer (score 44):

With [`delegate()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) , you assign it to a container, and the first argument is the element that should trigger the event.

Also, `.delegate()` accepts only one function, so for the `hover` event you need to test the `event.type` to determine [`show()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/show/)  or [`hide()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) .

```
$('.someContainer').delegate('.someTarget','hover', function( event ) {
    if( event.type === 'mouseenter' )  
        $('seconddiv').show();  
    else
        $('seconddiv').hide();  
});
```

For show/hide, a shorter way to write this is to use [`toggle()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), which can accept a *switch* argument where `true` means `show` and `false` means `hide`:

```
$('.someContainer').delegate('.someTarget','hover', function( event ) {
    $('seconddiv').toggle( event.type === 'mouseenter' );  
});
```

*Note that the `mouseenter` event is reported as of `jQuery 1.4.3`. If you're using `1.4.2`, it will be reported as `mouseover`.*

---

**EDIT:**

If I'm understanding your comments below, you'd have something like this (using the proper selectors of course).

```
$('mydiv').delegate('seconddiv','hover', function( event ) {
    $(this).toggle( event.type === 'mouseenter' );  
});
```

Comment: The seconddiv is within the first. When I use mouseover, it disappears once the mouse goes over the seconddiv, which was only displayed once I hovered over mydiv.

Comment: @Chris: Are you saying that when you hover over `mydiv`, you want its nested `seconddiv` to show, and then hide when you leave `mydiv`? Are the `mydiv` elements part of the page when it loads? Or are they added later?

Comment: seconddiv is nested in the first div. Sometimes mydiv is there on page load, and sometimes it is added after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: @Chris: I think I understand. I'll update and you can let me know If it was what you meant.

Comment: I did not realize that mouseenter was a type to choose from.

Comment: @Chris: Natively, it's only implemented in IE, but jQuery replicates its behavior. Basically just like mouseover, but it doesn't bubble, so place it on a parent container, and when you hover children of that container, it won't fire the handler. Only when you do a hover over the container itself.

Comment: This solution **stopped working** for me with **jQuery 1.9.1** in all major browsers. A workaround is to bind both the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events: `$('mydiv').delegate('seconddiv','mouseenter mouseleave', ...`. I couldn't find any information whether this is a bug or a feature of the new jQuery version and I filed a bug in the jQuery Tracker: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13470

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature. So you can't delegate to `hover` anymore. For some reason my edit was rejected, so I added an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I know the OP wanted a `delegate` solution (so was I when I bumped into this question...)

But after further *investigation* I found out its possible to achieve the same without *js/jquery* code at all

All you need is a bit of *CSS*

```
.someContainer .seconddiv{
    display : none;
}

.someContainer:hover .seconddiv{
    display : block;
}
```

INMO it a much more efficient/ligthwheigth solution

Comment: This is a nice way of doing it with CSS - when I was having this issue, I needed to fire another JS event once the mouse entered.

Comment: Be careful if you need to interact with something in `.seconddiv` on a touchscreen device... The ordering of events will fire hover first and then a click into `.seconddiv`

Answer (score 1):

`.delegate()` does not have a handle out. Also, you need the specify the element you are targeting with the first parameter.

You could try something like this, however:

```
$('table').delegate('tr', 'hover', function() {  
    $(this).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: misinformation removed.

If you want to use the `hover()` method without delegation, working code would look like this:

```
$('#mydiv').hover(function() {  
    $('#seconddiv').show();  
}, function() {  
    $('#seconddiv').hide();  
});
```

Second of all, `delegate` is to assign an event handler to a child, so you need to specify a selector first.  If you need to make sure this event handler exists for dynamically added elements, I would prefer `.live()` in this case with `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

```
$('#mydiv').live('mouseenter', function() {  
    $('#seconddiv').show();  
}).live('mouseleave', function() {  
    $('#seconddiv').hide();  
});
```

Comment: jQuery accepts `hover` as an event type for `bind`, `live` and `delegate`. It maps to `mouseenter/mouseleave`.

Comment: That's incorrect. `hover` IS an event type. It's even used as an example for `delegate` in the jQuery documentation. http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: Thank you.  It doesn't show in the API docs for the `.bind` method, so I didn't realize.

Comment: I was wrong about `bind`. It is only for `live` and `delegate`.

Comment: The second div is nested within the first, and if you hover over the second div, it will disappear.