# Dynamically added list item is not effected by earlier jquery function

Tags: jquery, list, hover, listitem

I've tried to make a list where I can add an item dynamically.

When you hover to a list item then color turns into yellow, otherwise the color will be red.
Adding a list item is no problem. if I add "item 6" (in addition to already existing 5 items)
adding goes without any problem, I can even sort it with other items. (using sortable from jquery ui).

The problem is "item 6" doesn't turn into yellow when I hover. It seems the hover function doesn't effect newly added item 6 while it still effects the first 5 items.

you can see how it works at  http://jsfiddle.net/9uNV2/  (without sortable)

The code is below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".list").sortable()

    $(".item").hover(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","yellow");
    },function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","orange");
    });

    $(".more").click(function(){
        $(".more").before("<div class=\"add-item\"><form action=\"\"><input class=\"new-    item\" type=\"text\" name=\"text\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\"></form></div>");
        $('.new-item').focus();
        $("form").submit(function(){
            var new_value = $(".new-item").val();
            event.preventDefault();
            $(".add-item").before("<div class=\"item\">" + new_value + "              </div>").trigger('item');
            $(".add-item").remove();
        });
    }); 
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="list">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item 5</div>
    <div class="more">Add more</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I make sure that "item 6" also be effected by hover function after it's added as 6th element. So it turns into yellow too when hover over it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hover` is not supported anymore, you need to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` like this:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", '.item', function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
}).on("mouseleave", '.item', function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "orange");
});
```

And you need to use the delegate syntax, to apply it to the newly append elements.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9uNV2/1/

Ref: [Does jQuery have a handleout for .delegate('hover')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772287/does-jquery-have-a-handleout-for-delegatehover?answertab=active#tab-top)