# Jquery issue - Hover class is never removed

Tags: jquery

I am building an application that initially displays a collection of pictures giving the user the possibility to select some of them and add them to another div.

For these dynamically added images I need to enable hovering functionality to enlarge images on hover.

This my Jquery approach:

```
$(document).on('hover','#zooming',function(){
            $("#zooming").addClass('hover');
    }
        , function() {
            $("#zooming").removeClass('hover');
        }

    );
```

css code:

```
#zooming{
  &.hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    color:white;
    background: #dbdbe0;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding:20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;

  }
}
```

when I use this approach the enlargement of image never happens after hovering.

When I use

```
 $(document).on('hover','#zooming',function(){
            $("#zooming").addClass('hover');
    }
   );
```

The image is enlarged but never goes back to its original size which is normal.
Could you spot what am I doing wrong here?

Thank you very much.

Comment: There is no `hover` event, you cannot then delegate it. `hover` method in jQuery is a shorthand for `mouseenter/mouseleave`, these events can be delegated, e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14938484/1414562

Comment: `When I use...` `The image is enlarged but never goes back to its original size which is normal` Looks like you are testing it wrongly too EDIT: or using older jQuery version

Comment: Thank you very much. I hadn't found that answer, it helped me a lot.