# jQuery: Hovering Over All Images Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get an over event over all images in a page, but some of them are not working.

The Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on('mouseenter', 'img', function(){
        console.log("hoving in");
    });
    $("body").on('mouseleave', 'img', function(){
        console.log("hoving out");
    });
});
```

Example URL: http://kr0npr1nz.deviantart.com/art/Tifa-Lockhart-sketch-468780450

The thumbnails on the right of the page aren't triggering the mouseenter/leave event.

Comment: The thumbnails on the right are not `<img>` elements. They are `<div>`s with `background-image` style.

Comment: @techfoobar ohhhhhhhh. I was misled because the `div` has an `img` element, but that `img` element was a "fake thumb" with a 1x1 dimension. I guess my code needs to be robust enough to account for not just any `img` elements, but every element with a `background image` attribute?

Comment: Exactly, account for images as well as all elements with a background-image, but ensure you dont includes elements, you don't want to include (for zooming?)

Answer (score -1):

use jquery hover:

```
$("img").hover(function(){
    console.log("hovering over");
},function(){
    console.log("hovering out");
});
```

see:  http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: That's not the problem, see @techfoobar comment.

Comment: Thanks for trying! I used "on" to account for dynamically generated images (images that are generated via ajax). I believe .hover does not account for that.

Comment: after you generate the images with ajax, you run the script again.  then it'll pick them up.  Just as long as you use <img> tags.  what i mean to say is you run the $("img").hover ... etc. stuff again.   e.g. make it a function (sorround with function imgreg(){ ... }, etc..

Comment: it's for this reason that often you need to do a $(document).ready(function(){ ... }) and throw your script in the "..." area so that the page will completely load first and then you register the jquery stuff.  happened to me a lot working with Jive stuff.

Comment: I don't need to call the function again if I simply use the .on event. That's what its for.

Comment: well, not really.  to use the on, you first have to generate the image then run the on command.  quote:  "The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object"  - that means on what's currently there, not stuff appearing in the future...  same idea w/ hover.

Comment: jQuery `.on()` function also handles delegated events, so it's not just the the currently selected elements.

Comment: If that is the case, I find this quote very confusing "Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on()."  this is from:  http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: anyways, here's an answer that might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772287/does-jquery-have-a-handleout-for-delegatehover

Comment: The syntax is $("body").on('click', 'img', function()... so the body exists on creation.