# class selectors on javascript generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**This was a dublicate question, George's link to a previous question had my answer**

I'm having an issue where selectors aren't functioning with dynamically generated javascript content.

The initial  works just fine.  Once the for loop generates more div's, even though it's got the same class, the 'mouseover' css styling won't apply.

Code that Generates the divs:

```
    for (x; x < y; x++) {
        output = output + '<div class="over">'+
            'But not for these generated divs'+ 
            '</div>';
    }
   $("#content").html(output);
```

Code that styles the divs with class "over":

```
$(".over").hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("styling");
});


$(".over").mouseout(function () {
    $(this).removeClass("styling");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kjhansen/1e08ypms/28/

Comment: I guess you mean JavaScript, not Java.

Comment: Sorry to be rude, but how the f did that question got 3 upvotes when is is asked 100 times a day?

Comment: Also related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772287/does-jquery-have-a-handleout-for-delegatehover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) Try this:

```
$(document).on('mouseover','.over',function () {
    $(this).addClass("styling");
});


$(document).on('mouseout','.over',function () {
    $(this).removeClass("styling");
});
```

**[FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1e08ypms/30/)**

Comment: or `$(document).on('mouseover mouseout','.over',function () { $(this).toggleClass("styling"); });`