# add event to cloned div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have `div class="choose-city` with `ul` within which has other `ul` inside

```
<div class="choose-city clearfix">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">City 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Other city</a>
                        <ul class="cities-list clearfix">
                            <li><a href="">City 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">City 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">City 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">City 5</a></li>                            
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

then I hide parent `div`

```
$('.header').stop(true).slideDown(400)
```

then I clone and appendTo my `div class="choose-city`

```
var choose_city = $('.header_inner .choose-city').clone().addClass('cloned').hide().appendTo('.map-container').show('200').animate({
            'top': '20px',
            'left': '40px'
        }, 200);
```

and I need to attach event on hover on inner `li` for original and cloned elements

I try to use this code

```
 $('body').on('hover', '$(".choose-city > ul > li").eq(1)', function () {

});
```

but it works only for original element, but not for cloned. What's wrong? How to fix it?

**upd.**
I add parameter `true` in my clone method

```
var choose_city = $('.header_inner .choose-city').clone(true).addClass('cloned').hide().appendTo('.map-container').show('200').animate({
            'top': '20px',
            'left': '40px'
        }, 200);
```

and then I tried a few ways to solve my problem and found this code works for original and cloned elements both

```
$('.choose-city > ul > li').eq(1).hover(function () {
    $(this).children('a').addClass('active');
    var sub_menu = $(this).find('.cities-list');
    sub_menu.stop(true).slideDown(100, function () {
        $(this).stop(true).animate({
            'opacity': 1
        }, 200);
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).find('a').removeClass('active');
    var sub_menu = $(this).find('.cities-list');
    sub_menu.stop(true).slideUp(100, function () {
        $(this).stop(true).animate({
            'opacity': 0
        }, 200);
    });
});
```

but this code doesn't work for no one element

```
$('body').delegate('$(".choose-city > ul > li:eq(1)")', 'hover', function ( event ) {
    if (event.type === 'mouseenter') {
        console.log("test1");
        $(this).children('a').addClass('active');
        var sub_menu = $(this).find('.cities-list');
        console.log('sub_menu');
        sub_menu.stop(true).slideDown(100, function () {
            $(this).stop(true).animate({
                'opacity': 1
            }, 200);
        });
    } else {
        $(this).find('a').removeClass('active');
        var sub_menu = $(this).find('.cities-list');
        sub_menu.stop(true).slideUp(100, function () {
            $(this).stop(true).animate({
                'opacity': 0
            }, 200);
        });
    }
});
```

and I don't understand why?

Comment: `clone(true)` http://api.jquery.com/clone/ ??? FYI, `hover` isn't an event but a shorthand method event, to delegate it see e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14938484/1414562

Comment: Also instead of `'$(".choose-city > ul > li").eq(1)'` simply use `".choose-city > ul > li:eq(1)"`

Comment: thanks a lot for help, I updated my question, can you explain me please what's wrong?