# jQuery hover AJAX loaded content not working

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I get content though AJAX like:

```
<div class="nachricht" id="1">
    bla
    <div class="detail" id="1" style="float: left; display: none;">hidden stuff</div>
    <div class="spacer" style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

and I want `.details` to be shown on hover on `.nachricht`

so I use:

```
$(".nachricht").hover(function(){
    $(".detail", this).stop(true,true).delay(500).show(0);
    }, function (){
    $(".detail", this).stop(true,true).delay(500).hide(0);
});
```

Why isn't it working when loaded though AJAX and how could I solve it?

**EDIT:**

I get the content from functions like:

```
function loadfile(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'donachrichten.php',
        data: {mach: "loadfile", kontaktfile: kontaktfile},
        success: function(data){
             $("#chatnow").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Simple answer is element doesn't exist when code runs. Show ajax code. Can put the code in ajax callback that inserts the html , or convert to delegated `mouseenter mouseleave` events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using this:

```
 $("#chatnow").on('mouseenter', '.nachricht', function( event ) {
    $(".detail", this).stop(true,true).delay(500).show(0);
}).on('mouseleave', '.nachricht', function( event ) {
    $(".detail", this).stop(true,true).delay(500).hide(0);
});
```

**explanation**

As `.nachricht` class item doesnot exist when the your page loaded, you can't bind event with non-existing element. instead use event delegation on element `#chatnow` should work.

[Here are some more example of hover event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14938484/1289495)

Comment: PS: ( event ) isn't necessary it can be just ()

Answer (score 1):

Why not handle the show/hide with css instead? First, remove the inline styles from the .detail div, then add this to your stylesheet.

```
.detail {float:left;display:none}
.nachricht:hover .detail {display:block;}
```

Otherwise wrap your initial hover function in a function.

```
function showDetails(){
$(".nachricht").hover(function(){
    $(".detail", this).stop(true,true).delay(500).show(0);
}, function (){
    $(".detail", this).stop(true,true).delay(500).hide(0);
});
}
```

and call it after the data has been loaded.

```
success: function(data){
         $("#chatnow").html(data);
         showDetails();
    }
```

Comment: There is no delay effect in CSS (I think) but I like your other solution, it's good to know that it would work this way too I might use it for other things

Comment: Actually there is and if you used it in combination with the opacity property instead of display, it would work quite nicely. Although it's not as cross-browser friendly as your jquery method.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-delay.asp